# mdmclient in OS X is not responding to mdm commands just sends idle but doesn't perform or Acknowlegde the sent command

Tags: ios, macos, apple-push-notifications, mdm

The mdmclient in OS X is not responding to mdm commands just sends idle in response to the command but doesn't perform the action or Acknowledge or Command Format Error. please help in tracing down the issue.same server config works fine in iOS .. used 1024 for access rights  to  support OSX

I'm Using Self Signed Server Cert with correct Subject Alt name i.e DNS and IP Address ,Self Signed CA and Identity is generated by SCEP.

the Device Response.. to apns notification

```
            <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
            <plist version="1.0"> 
                <dict> 
                    <key>Status</key> 
                    <string>Idle</string> 
                    <key>UDID</key> 
                    <string>nnjknjkjknjk</string> 
                    <key>UserID</key> 
                    <string>nnjknjkjknjk</string> 
                    <key>UserLongName</key> 
                    <string>cdffefeef</string> 
                    <key>UserShortName</key> 
                    <string>fefef</string> 
                </dict> 
            </plist>
```

Sent Command for OSX is

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0"> 
    <dict> 
         <key>Command</key> 
         <dict> 
             <key>PIN</key> 
             <string>123456</string> 
             <key>RequestType</key> 
             <string>DeviceLock</string> 
         </dict> 
             <key>CommandUUID</key> 
             <string>some uuid</string> 
     </dict> 
</plist>
```

Any Help in this regards is really appreciated.. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify your content type, if content type is wrong it may also return idle response constantly. we faced that problem.Response to the device content type is : application/x-apple-aspen-mdm; charset=UTF-8.

Thanks.

Comment: thanks it solved my issue.. it worked fine in iOS with content type application/xml but OS X required application/x-apple-aspen-mdm; charset=UTF-8 to execute the command.

Answer (score 0):

For us it works with content-type "application/xml".
But we had an issue with the chunked "Transfer-Encoding" type authorized by HTTP/1.1 (protocol used by OS X MDM!!!).

**So by setting Content-Length and, by the way, avoiding chunked transfer encoding it worked.**

Note: We worked with tomcat, and tomcat automatically add "chunked" transfer encoding for HTTP/1.1 if you did not set content length (even with a 'deflate' compression).